# How to turn off strongloop loopback-testing console logging?

Tags: javascript, node.js, loopbackjs, strongloop

I have a very simple test case of API done with usage of loopback-testing module.

```
lt = require('loopback-testing')
assert = require('assert')

describe '/profile', ->
  lt.beforeEach.withApp app

  lt.describe.whenCalledRemotely 'GET', '/api/profiles/ping', { data: 'test' }, ->
    lt.it.shouldBeAllowed()

    it 'should have statusCode 200', ->
      assert.equal @res.statusCode, 200

    it 'should have pong response', ->
      assert.equal @res.body.pong, 'test'
```

and as result of testing I'm getting printed lines at the system console like this ones:

```
 /profile
    GET /api/profiles/ping
GET /api/profiles/ping 200 50.639 ms - 15
      ✓ should be allowed
GET /api/profiles/ping 200 8.026 ms - 15
      ✓ should have statusCode 200
GET /api/profiles/ping 200 3.633 ms - 15
      ✓ should have pong response
```

Is there a way to turn off writing these lines to system console by loopback-testing module? It's simply trashes my mocha reports overview.

Answer (score 0):

Do you have any logging middleware configured in your application? The extra lines look like HTTP access logs produced by [morgan](https://www.npmjs.com/package/morgan).

You need to disable any HTTP logging middleware in your application when running the tests. The instructions for that depend on how you have configured this middleware, could you please extend your question and describe your app setup?